# Show $E$ is a valid expectation operator

Tags: probability-theory

Hello I am working within the confines of Probability via Expectation by Whittle. In this approach the expectation operator is given certain axioms. Thus I must answer the question from this perspective.

$$ E(H(x))= p H(0) + \int_0^\infty H(t) f(t) \, dt $$

I must show under what conditions on $p$ and $f(t)$ the above is a valid expectation operator. $H(x)$ is a random variable with $x$ being in the sample space of all positive numbers. I concluded that if $H(x)=x$ then it must be that $f(t)\ge 0$ and that $\int_0^\infty f(t) \, dt=1$. Then if $H(x)=1$ since $E(1)=1$ (an axiom) that $p=0$. However that would mean this is a trick question so I want to make sure I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion makes no sense. If $H(x)=x$, then $E(x)=\int_0^\infty tf(t)dt$ and there is no reason why this should have to equal 1. Look at the axioms you need.

First you need that $E(1)=1$. This gives $\int_0^\infty f(t)dt=1-p$.

Comment: Well if a rv $X$ has expectation $\int_0^{\infty} X(t)f(t)$ then $f(t)$ must have those properties I mentioned

Comment: That's what I based that conclusion off of. Since in the case $H(x)=x, E(H(X))= \int_0^{\infty} tf(t)$